# Passing Array bi dimensional from controller to view in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

Hello I'm trying to pass an array bidimensional, the array is reads with a foreach and every round the foreach adds a new Array in my ArrUsers. So I need to send array to view.php but when I read the foreach in a view  this just show the information to the last array, but I need the info of the all arrays.

In my controller I pass the array from controller.php to view.php:

```
$this->view->ArrUsersL = $ArrUsers;
```

In my controller I print the array for view your conent;
print_r($ArrUsers);

And the result is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [username] => User1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [username] => User2
        )

)

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [username] => User3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [username] => User4
        )

)
```

And In my view I use foreach to read my Array:

```
<?php 
  foreach ($ArrUsersL as $key => $value) {
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($value);
    echo "<pre>";
    }
?>
```

And the result is:

```
Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [username] => User3
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [username] => User4
            )

    )
```

But I need the two arrays:

```
  Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [username] => User1
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [username] => User2
            )

    )

    Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [username] => User3
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [username] => User4
            )

    )
```

why? Thanks In advance

Comment: it looks like the second call with User3 and User4 is overwriting the results of the first call and erasing User1 and User2

Comment: exactly, the 2nd call override the result's, how avoid it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from php.net:

> If you want to append array elements from the second array to the
>   first array while not overwriting the elements from the first array
>   and not re-indexing, use the + array union operator:

look at this page here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

Comment: Thaks For the Info, :)